# ¿Quisiera saber como paso un valor de la vista al constructor del ViewModel?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Lo que intento es pasar parámetros para realizar consultas con el uso del Id_Carrera, pero necesito saber como pasarlo.
Realizo un ObservableCollection con una consulta hecha a una tabla (llamada Carreras).
Utilizo el ItemTapped para mandar los datos a otra vista. Lo que quiero es que en la nueva vista mostrar otra ObservableCollection con la consulta hecha.

```
using PagosUTSC.Modelos;
using PagosUTSC.VistaModelo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace PagosUTSC.Vistas
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CarrerasVista : ContentPage
    {
        public CarrerasVista()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BtnNuevo.Clicked += Btnnuevo_Clicked;
        }
/*Aqui envío datos, pero solo ala vista*/
        private async void OnSelectedItem(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

            var id = e.Item as Carreras;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new GruposVista(id.Id_Carrera, id.NombreCarrera));
        }
        private async void Btnnuevo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertarCarrera view = new InsertarCarrera();
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(view);

        }
    }
}
```

Necesito pasar el Id_Carrera de la lista generada en la vista, para realizar la nueva consulta, con GetGrupos.

```
using PagosUTSC.Base;
using PagosUTSC.Modelos;
using PagosUTSC.Repositorios;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PagosUTSC.VistaModelo
{
    public class GrupoVistaModelo : VistaMoldeloBase
    {
/*Necesito el parametro num, que sería el Id_carrera.*/
        public GrupoVistaModelo()
        {
            GrupoRepos repo = new GrupoRepos();
            List<Grupos> lista = repo.GetGrupos(num);
            this.Grupos = new ObservableCollection<Grupos>(lista);
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Grupos> _Grupos;
        public ObservableCollection<Grupos> Grupos
        {
            get { return this._Grupos; }
            set
            {
                this._Grupos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Grupos");
            }
        }
    }
}
```